# How to get correct item of position in a custom list view even after the list is re-arranged?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to sort the list items of a custom adapter List view. After sorting from original listview, if list item is clicked, the original position of item in list view is seen but not the sorted element's. It is a problem that, even after the custom list view is sorted, the previous original listview item is only accessible. even when the list view items are re-arranged, the list items maintaining the original position values as id. how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are creating a new adapter then simply set the adapter to listview and then give a delay and notifydatasetchanged should be called.
This should solve your problem sometimes delay is needed ..

Answer (score 1):

Please use notifyDataSetChanged at and invalidate the ListAdapter at proper Place to avoid the  corrupted data

Comment: where should place notifyDataSetChanged in getview method?

Comment: No No it will go in LOOP. place this method before setAdapter

Comment: no effect for this notifyDataSetChanged when placed before setAdapter.